# Why is my hello-1.c and Makefile not producing .ko files?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, makefile, linux-kernel

I am following the Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide's hello world programming examples (pg 8-9): https://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/lkmpg.pdf

I have the following hello-1.c as described in the guide:

```
/*
 * hello−1.c − The simplest kernel module.
 */
#include <linux/module.h> /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h> /* Needed for KERN_INFO */

int init_module(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");
    /*
    * A non 0 return means init_module failed; module can't be loaded.
    */
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

Along with the Makefile on page 9:

```
obj−m += hello−1.o

all:
    sudo make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

When I use the Makefile with make, I get the following output:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-60-generic/build M=/home/joeyoneill/Desktop/CSCI614 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 0 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic'
```

and 2 files (Module.symvers and modules.order) are made.

However, I do not get:

```
hostname:~/lkmpg−examples/02−HelloWorld# make
make −C /lib/modules/2.6.11/build M=/root/lkmpg−examples/02−HelloWorld modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux−2.6.11'
 CC [M] /root/lkmpg−examples/02−HelloWorld/hello−1.o
 Building modules, stage 2.
 MODPOST
 CC /root/lkmpg−examples/02−HelloWorld/hello−1.mod.o
 LD [M] /root/lkmpg−examples/02−HelloWorld/hello−1.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux−2.6.11'
hostname:~/lkmpg−examples/02−HelloWorld#
```

Which is the output that the book gives and so I am not creating this .o or .ko file.
Shown with the lines:

```
 CC /root/lkmpg−examples/02−HelloWorld/hello−1.mod.o
 LD [M] /root/lkmpg−examples/02−HelloWorld/hello−1.ko
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: A common cause of this is copying from a PDF file. If that is what you did then suggest you start a new makefile and type out the contents.

Comment: Or find a text editor shows abnormal characters.

Comment: In your Makefile `obj-m` uses wrong dash symbol.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide is now maintained for v5.x kernels, and you can get the book along with working examples: https://github.com/sysprog21/lkmpg